# Как сделать выбор количества комбинаций?

Tags: javascript

Здесь в коде указано показать 100 комбинаций. Как сделать Раскрывающийся список (select), в котором можно будет выбрать количество комбинаций для показа?

```js
function  generate() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
  const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
  let resultSet = new Map();
  while (resultSet.size < 100) {
    let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
    let key = (nums.sort() + '');
    resultSet.set(key, nums);
  }
  resultSet.forEach(val => {
    const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
   document.getElementById("myTable").append(main);
    
   
  })
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    return {
      item: el,
      sort: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}



function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
  const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tableEl.className = className || "";
  tableEl.append(content);
  return tableEl;
  
}
```

```html
<input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Получить комбинации" onclick="generate()" />
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример с `<input type="text">`. Переделать на селект не должно составить труда.

```js
function  generate() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
  const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
  let resultSet = new Map();
  let qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
  while (resultSet.size < qnt) {
    let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
    let key = (nums.sort() + '');
    resultSet.set(key, nums);
  }
  resultSet.forEach(val => {
    const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
   document.getElementById("myTable").append(main);
    
   
  })
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    return {
      item: el,
      sort: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}



function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
  const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tableEl.className = className || "";
  tableEl.append(content);
  return tableEl;
  
}
```

```html
<input id="quantity" type="text" value='100'/>
<input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Получить комбинации" onclick="generate()" />
<div id="myTable"></div>
```